# If I have an array of pointers to strings (words), how can i access each word individually?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I'm writing a function, which receives an empty array of pointers, the amount of words the the function should scan at most(size) (btw it can scan less than size amount of words), and the maximum length of a word(which I should ensure a word doesnt surpass).

Here is my code (I'm using C & the lines with arrows give an error):

```
void read_words(char* words[], int size, int max_str_len)
{
    int i=0;

    while( (i<size ) && (scanf("%s", & *words[i]) != EOF ))
    {
    
1->      if(strlen(*words[i]) > max_str_len )       
        {
2->          *words[i][max_str_len-1] = '\0';         
        }
    }
}
```

after getting a bunch of errors I realised that the errors come from the fact that the pointers array only points to the first char of the sequence (meaning only the first letters of the words).

(the first line arrow also gave mr the following error:
error: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast)

So the question is, how can I fix it? how do I get the entire word or get to the end of it? if I change it to " *words[i] + max_str_len " does it fix the problem? but in that case I might get the value of a different variable sitting in the memory...

any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Tip: Makes sense to do the `i<size` first and then `scanf()`.

Comment: `*words[i].strlen()` does not look like C.  Did you mean `strlen(words[i])`?

Comment: `'/0'` certainly should be `'\0'`.

Comment: I assume `max_str_len` is (one greater than) the maximum number of characters that each `word` can hold.  If you write more than that number into each word (which `scanf` will happily do), the behavior will be undefined.  Attempting to truncate the string after the fact by writing a null character at the end will not avoid the problem.

Comment: What does "empty array of pointers" mean? Were the pointers already allocated by the caller, or does the function need to allocate them?

Comment: An array element is accessed with `array[index]`, not `*array[index]` as you're doing everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just allow `scanf` to write arbitrarily long strings into each word, or you will overflow the buffer by writing `max_str_len` or more characters.  Instead, you need to limit how much `scanf` will write with something like:

```
char fmt[32];
sprintf(fmt, "%%%ds", max_str_len - 1);
while( (i < size) && (scanf(fmt, words[i]) == 1) ){
   ...
```

In general, you should never use `%s` without a maximum field width as a conversion specifier in a scanf format string, since `scanf` can easily overflow the bounds of the array that it is writing to.  If `buf` has N characters allocated, the format string should look like `%Ms` where M == N - 1 to allow space for the null terminator.  In the example above, we use `sprintf` to generate the desired format string.

Note that if any of the strings in the input exceed the maximum length, those strings will be split into more than once `word` in your array.  You'll need to decide how you want to deal with that situation and add the appropriate logic.

Comment: The argument to `scanf` should be `words[i]`, not `words + i`. There are also numerous other issues with OP's code.

Comment: @interjay Thanks for pointing that out!  Edited.

Comment: thank you for your help, but in the same sense of the problem above, I'm still getting the same errors in a different function: let's say the function scanned size amount of words, and I want to write a while loop to print them all, what would the code be? I tried but it's the same problem that i had at first, each pointer in the array only point to the first letterof each word not the entire word...

Comment: That's how strings work.  If you write `char buf[] = "abcedfg"; char *aptr = buf; printf("%s\n", aptr)`, then `aptr` points to the `a` at the start of `buf`, and `printf` writes the whole string.

Comment: that's the problem , it's not printing, the program gets terminated the second it gets to the line: printf("%s \n", *words[i]);

Comment: `words[i]` is a `char *` and is appropriate to pass as the argument to `printf` to match a `%s` directive in the format string.  But `*words[i]` is a char.  IOW, you want `printf("%s\n", words[i]);`